# Can I combine vhdx and avhdx file to save disk space?

Tags: windows-10, hyper-v

I create a VM on my Windows 10 machine. Originally, it only has 1 vhdx file for my virtual hard disk. But now, it creates another file *.avhdx for the disk.

Is there a way to combine them?
the vhdx file is 255GB and the avhdx is 139 GB.

Can you please tell me how can I safely remove the avhdx file to save space?

Comment: avhdx is a file for the snapshot feature within Hyper-V, even if you could merge the two files, the amount of storage used woudln't change.  If you don't care about the snapshots then delete them.

Comment: In My VM, I see my C: is 300GB. but when I go to host , I add vhdx and avhdx file, they are 267gb+145GB , that is much more than 300GB

Comment: Like I said you can delete the past snapshots if you want to save space.

Comment: I remove the *.avhdx file, but now my VM won't even start. It said the *.avhdx file is not found.

Comment: I didn't say it was safe to delete the files by themselfs.  You should have deleted the snapshots from within Hyper-V.  If you take a look at what what I said in my comment that was clear.